# Create class with arguments or call its methods separately

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

How JS code should be structered when instantiating new classes inside controller class `Main`.

Solutions:

A: pass arguments while creating new class - `new Options(args)` - and let `Options`'s constructor call its own methods.

B: create new class and call the classes' methods on the object.

Later I'd use properties from `Options` in another classes.

```
// A
class Main {
 constructor(options) {
    this.options = new Options(options);

    { firstProperty, secondProperty } = this.options;
    this.another = new Another(firstProperty, secondProperty);
  }
}

// B
class Main {
 constructor(options) {
    this.options = new Options();
    const firstProperty = this.options.methodA(options);
    const secondProperty = this.options.methodB(options);

    this.another = new Another();
    const anotherPropety = this.another.methodA(firstProperty);
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: The two codes don't seem equivalent. in B you don't copy both properties to `this.another`. Also, should `this.other` be `this.another`?

Comment: They're equivalent, I should add 'etc...'. Now, it's `another` only, it was mistake, thank you for spotting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of decoupling I would suggest a third option.

```
//main.js
class Main {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options;
    // all instances of class would have:
    this.options.foo = 'bar'
  }

  method() {
    return `${this.options.foo} - ${this.options.setup}`
  }
}

// example.js
const options = new Options({setup: 'options'});
const example = new Main(options);
console.log(example.method());
```

This lets your inject your dependencies into a given class, which makes writing tests for your code far simpler. It also gives you the benefit of (as long as you maintain a common interface) swapping out `Options` for `NewAwesomeOptions` at some later point without having to find everywhere you might have hard coded it into a class.

Comment: So the `Main` would have access to all methods from `Options`. The file 'example.js' now is a controller/dispatcher. I need central object which initialize new objects, passing them needed properties from other objects - like your 'example.js'.

Comment: Pretty much yeah, this relies on the principles of [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  In practice it helps decouple the pieces of your code so that parts can be more interchangeable, this is helpful in test mocking as well as improving code reusability and extensibility.